# How do I show an application only in the dock assigned to a desktop?

Tags: dock, desktop

You can assign the application in the dock to a desktop. But can you hide the application in the dock in the desktop where it is not assigned? That is, the dock in each desktop should show only the app icons that are assigned to that desktop. Possible? Within OS X or via an app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.